# Is there a way the get the sum of randomly generated numbers?

Tags: python, sum, integer

I'm still very new to python so this code is probably not the best way to achieve what I'm looking for.
But regardless, I basically want to create a code that will perform a dice rolling formula and output a total value I can use for data.
what I want to do is get the sum of random generated numbers, however, the amount of numbers generated varies on certain factors, so it can be anywhere from 1 to 3.

Here is a visual representation of what i want:

Roll 3x d20:

(12)(6)(14)

Roll d6 for each value that's equal or greater than 10:

(6)(N/A)(3)

Add 6 to each value"

6+6 = 12

3=6 =  9

(I got the code working up until the above step )

subtract 8 from above values:

12-8 =4

9-8  =1

total:

4+1 = 5

Also I know adding 6 and then subtracting 8 might sound stupid but there's a reason I need it this way.

This is the code I have so far:

```
import random
while True:
    print("_______________________________")
    input("press enter to start")
    d201 = random.randint(1,20)
    d202 = random.randint(1,20)
    d203 = random.randint(1,20)
    d61 = random.randint(1,6)
    d62 = random.randint(1,6)
    d63 = random.randint(1,6)
    hit = [d201 ,d202 ,d203]
    dmg = [d61 ,d62 ,d63]
    db = 6


print("hit rolls")
print(hit)
print("damage rolls")
if d201 >= 10:
    print(d61, '(roll 1)')
if d202 >= 10:
    print(d62, '(roll 2)')    
if d203 >= 10:
    print(d63, '(roll 3)')

print("damage bonus:")    

if d201 >= 10:
    print((d61 + db), '(roll 1)+6')
if d202 >= 10:
    print((d62 + db), '(roll 2)+6')    
if d203 >= 10:
    print((d63 + db), '(roll 3)+6')

print("damage total:")
```

So my first attempt  was to add the (d61 + db) , (d62 + db) and (d63 + db) as variables and the creating a variable for those 3, and lastly print the sum of the variable:

```
dt = [(d61 + db) ,(d62 + db) ,(d63 + db)]
    total = sum(dt)
```

And then at the end of the code:

```
print("damage total:")
    print(total)
```

How ever this gives me the wrong total, its clearly not taking the results from the previous values.

Comment: In short, yes, there's a way. Can you show us your attempt at the later steps, so we can help you identify the issues?

Comment: Also if you're saying that it's giving the wrong total, what is the total that it is giving, what were you expecting, and what is the output of all those print statements leading up to it?

Comment: The totals I would get would be random numbers like 8, 25, 10 and so on, no real pattern to them. I think what is happening is, its re-rolling the dice and then adding them together, instead of using the results from the previous formula.